# Linq groupby and global count (not count per group)

Tags: linq, entity-framework-core

I have the following query:

```
var query = from incident in _dbContext.VehicleIncidents
                    join vehicle in _dbContext.Vehicles on incident.VehicleId equals vehicle.Id
                    where vehicle.EnterpriseId == enterpriseId
                    group incident by new {incident.ReportDate.Month, incident.ReportDate.Year}
                    into g1
                    orderby g1.Key.Year, g1.Key.Month
                    select new
                    {
                        Month = g1.Key.Month,
                        Year = g1.Key.Year,
                        Cost = g1.Sum(o => o.Cost)
                    };
```

It returns all the incidents aggregated by month and year. But I need the total number of incidents too. Not the incidents for every group, but the total count. The sum of the incidents of all groups. Can this be done in this query or is it better to just roll another query just to get the total global count?

Answer (score 0):

I believe you could get the sum per group and then sum those. Something like

```
var query = from incident in _dbContext.VehicleIncidents
                join vehicle in _dbContext.Vehicles on incident.VehicleId equals vehicle.Id
                where vehicle.EnterpriseId == enterpriseId
                group incident by new {incident.ReportDate.Month, incident.ReportDate.Year}
                into g1
                orderby g1.Key.Year, g1.Key.Month
                select new
                {
                    Month = g1.Key.Month,
                    Year = g1.Key.Year,
                    Cost = g1.Sum(o => o.Cost),
                    Count = g1.Count()
                };
var total = queryResult.SUM(x=>x.count);
```

The other alternative I see is to join a sub query see [Join Subquery result in Linq](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16166151/join-subquery-result-in-linq)

something like

```
var subquery = from incident in _dbContext.VehicleIncidents
                    join vehicle in _dbContext.Vehicles on incident.VehicleId equals vehicle.Id
                    where vehicle.EnterpriseId == enterpriseId
                    into g1
                    select new
                    {
                        Total = g1.Count()
                    };

var query = from incident in _dbContext.VehicleIncidents
                    join vehicle in _dbContext.Vehicles on incident.VehicleId equals vehicle.Id
join sub in subquery on 1=1
                    where vehicle.EnterpriseId == enterpriseId
                    group incident by new {incident.ReportDate.Month, incident.ReportDate.Year}
                    into g1
                    orderby g1.Key.Year, g1.Key.Month
                    select new
                    {
                        Month = g1.Key.Month,
                        Year = g1.Key.Year,
                        Cost = g1.Sum(o => o.Cost),
                        Count = sub.total
                    };
```

Comment: I see, that is something I thought too. But wanted to know if everything could be done on the DB side. If no one suggests a better solution I will accept this. Thanks.